# App users logged geolocation - which location is most important?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, folium

I am working with an application that logs the geolocation of all users. It is now important that I select the most important geolocation from each user for a certain time period. For example; for a certain user I have the following locations of the last month.

```
    long    lat
2236    51.471899   5.471339
3432    51.461456   5.486195
3433    51.454544   5.487742
3434    51.471934   5.471232
3567    51.441648   5.464492
3568    51.398149   5.478717
3569    51.467318   5.470221
3570    51.467257   5.478014
3571    51.468200   5.477699
3572    51.443477   5.472390
```

It is important to select only one coordinate of this list that summarizes where the user most likely will open the app. This will be the place where we have to focus our resources on. 
*The main question*: **How do i determine which geolocation of each user within a certain time period is most important?**

Here I plotted the geolocations of one user on a map provided by the Python library named *folium*

Map with geolocations from one specific user :
[image]

*My current best idea to solve this problem*
For each geolocation i take a radius of x meters around the geolocation. I count how many other geolocations of this specific user fall within this redius. The geolocation with the most other geolocations within it's radius is seen as the most important geolocation of that specific user.

*My question to you guys*
I am new to solving these kind of problems and I have no idea whether my solution is the best to pick or whether there are better solutions to solve such a problem. Any feedback from you guys on this problem would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is probably not the right place to ask, but you can find some hints for example here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/761/clustering-geo-location-coordinates-lat-long-pairs. My personal opinion for a quick solution: Transform your data so that you can ignore haversine and use kmeans with euclidean distance.

Comment: `It is important to select only one coordinate of this list that summarizes where the user most likely will open the app` timestamps would be helpful here.  ie Where a person is likely to be at 8am would be different than at 3pm

Answer (score 0):

a begginning of solution, you have to install geopy to simplify the calcul of distance: i suppose id is a location id and i calcul all distances (km) between all locations id

```
from geopy.distance import lonlat,distance

df= pd.DataFrame({'id': [2236, 3432, 3433, 3434, 3567, 3568, 3569, 3570, 3571, 3572],
                  'lon': [51.471899, 51.461456, 51.454544, 51.471934, 51.441648, 51.398149, 51.467318, 51.467257, 51.4682, 51.443477],
                  'lat': [5.471339, 5.486195, 5.487742, 5.471232, 5.464492, 5.478717, 5.470221, 5.478014, 5.477699, 5.47239]})

df_all = pd.merge(df.assign(key=0), df.assign(key=0),suffixes=('', '_loc') , on='key').drop('key', axis=1)

df_all['KM'] = df_all.apply(
    (lambda row:distance(lonlat(row['lon'], row['lat']),lonlat(row['lon_loc'], row['lat_loc'])).km),    axis=1)


print(df_all)
```

output:

```
      id        lon       lat  id_loc    lon_loc   lat_loc        KM
0   2236  51.471899  5.471339    2236  51.471899  5.471339  0.000000
1   2236  51.471899  5.471339    3432  51.461456  5.486195  2.009507
2   2236  51.471899  5.471339    3433  51.454544  5.487742  2.643655
3   2236  51.471899  5.471339    3434  51.471934  5.471232  0.012452
:
10  3432  51.461456  5.486195    2236  51.471899  5.471339  2.009507
11  3432  51.461456  5.486195    3432  51.461456  5.486195  0.000000
12  3432  51.461456  5.486195    3433  51.454544  5.487742  0.784811
:
70  3570  51.467257  5.478014    2236  51.471899  5.471339  0.899710
71  3570  51.467257  5.478014    3432  51.461456  5.486195  1.109818
:
98  3572  51.443477  5.472390    3571  51.468200  5.477699  2.801878
99  3572  51.443477  5.472390    3572  51.443477  5.472390  0.000000

(100 rows)
```

hope that could help and sorry for my poor english

Comment: if this answer helps you, please, dont forget to uvpvote/validate the answer !!